# Kotlin: mapNotNull but log what caused null elements

Tags: kotlin

When translating Java to Kotlin code, I encountered the following:

```
List<Content> getContent(List<Node> nodes, Map<String, Content> content) {
  List<Content> result = new ArrayList<>(nodes.size());
  for (Node node : nodes) {
    Content content = content.get(node.getId());
    if (content == null) {
      logger.atSevere().log("Content %s was not found", node.getId());
      continue;
    }
    result.add(content);
  }
  return result;
}
```

In Kotlin, this can be easily translated if we drop the logger call:

```
fun getContent(items: List<Node>, content: Map<String, Content): List<Content> {
  val contentIds = items.mapNotNull { it.id }
  return contentIds.mapNotNull { contentMap[it] }
}
```

I'm thinking a sequence builder might be nice here. It's also possible to separate out `contentIds` into two separate collections, one made up of the `contentIds` that were not present in `contentMap`, the other made up of the `Content` mapped to successfully. I bet there is also a better way to get a set of items in a map from a set of keys, but I haven't found the right function.

Comment: `contentMap[it].also { v -> if (v == null) print("...") }`. Or, more nasty: `contentMap[it].also { v -> v ?: print("...") }`

Comment: @dyukha This should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
fun check(items: List<Node>, content: Map<String, Content?>): List<Content>{
    return items.filter{
            if (content[it.id] == null){
              print("content " + it.id + "was not found")   
            }
            content[it.id] != null
        }.map{content[it.id]!!} 
}
```

Comment: dyukha's comment is a _far_ better option.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it's a matter of choice. I find my answer to more readable. The timing of my answer and dyukha's comment is almost similar.  The problem can be solved both ways!